# Why is the output of these two statements different？

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a python program, define a list: `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

The output results of executing the following two statements are different:

1:

```
list1 = my_list[1:9:2]
print(list1)
```

output:`[2, 4, 6, 8]`

2:

```
list2 = my_list[1::2]
print(list2)
```

output:`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

I can't understand why there is no "10" in the output of the first statement

Comment: Might want to review this: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing).

Comment: Why would you expect the second one not to include 10?

Comment: oh I think I get it
`a[:stop]  # items from the beginning through stop-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list1 = my_list[1:9:2] It would be enough to write 10 instead of 9 here.

Comment: At first I was worried that changing the 9 of `my_list[1:9:2]` to 10 would overflow.
Now I think I get it.
Thanks.